# varying output while testing function with urllib.parse.urlencode

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I am trying test below function

```
def get(id, uri):
    resource_uri = '{uri}projects/{id}/meta'.format(
        uri=uri,
        id=id)
    uri_parameters_list = {
        'PropertyTypes': 'true',
        'RichTextAsPlain': 'true' }
    request_uri = '{uri}?{parameters}'.format(
        uri=resource_uri,
        parameters=urllib.parse.urlencode(uri_parameters_list) )

    return request_uri
```

Below is the test code

```
  def test_prep_get_metadata(self):
    request_uri = "http://api/projects/3/meta?PropertyTypes=true&RichTextAsPlain=true"
    self.assertEqual(get(self.id,self.uri),request_uri)
```

when i run the above test code it runs perfectly sometimes and sometimes it throws an Assertion error saying

Error:

```
http://api/projects/3/meta?RichTextAsPlain=true&PropertyTypes=true!=http://api/projects/3/meta?   PropertyTypes=true&RichTextAsPlain=true
```

In the error you can see that elements in parameters list are swapped. Can anyone tell me how to stop them from swapping or is there any other way to test such type of function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `urllib.parse.urlencode(uri_parameters_list)` with a dictionary `uri_parameters_list` and the order of a dictionary isn't determined. It can vary from one Python run to the next as the elements aren't ordered (well, they are internally but that order can vary).

So you'll need to order the dictionary prior to passing it to `urllib.parse.urlencode`. It's better to use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in this case:

```
import collections

uri_parameters_list = collections.OrderedDict([
    ('PropertyTypes', 'true'),
    ('RichTextAsPlain', 'true'),
])
```